Thingsboard CE. How to zoom/pan the editing area for chain rules
Thing might be a silly question but I can't find a way to either zoom out of the rule chain editor screen, or pan around it, and this led me to a bad error I had to find out the bad way
I copied a set of 6 nodes from one ruleset and pasted it into another rule set. The paste process put some of the nodes above the upper margin, leaving me with no way to reach it, nor zoom out to see it. So I closed the chain rule to open it again, when I realized the ruleset wouldn't open!!!
I was terrified as this is a critical client with downlink commands to activate pumps, etc...
There was no way to open the ruleset at all.
This is how I fixed it: Downloaded the ruleset with the DOWNLOAD button at the chain rule list. Then I opened the JSON file and found that the lost nodes had negative Y coordinates which made the whole ruleset unable to be displayed. I removed the "bad" nodes and imported the JSON again, deleting the old one, and this worked again! This scared me tbh...
So now that I need to do it again and add these extra nodes that could show up above the top margin again, how do I zoom/pan in the nodes screen?
Thanks in advance!

No one? I see it really dangerous to let some rule node take coordinates Y<0, and also as it could go out of your scope, you don't even realize it's up there
